# Git incorrectly marking conflicts as resolved

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

Something is causing Git to automatically "resolve" merge conflicts.

Below is the actual, line for line output of an attempted merge:

```
>> git status
On branch BRANCH-A
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/BRANCH-A'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
>> git merge BRANCH-B
Auto-merging file1.css
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file1.css
Auto-merging file2.css
Auto-merging file3.scss
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file3.scss
Auto-merging file4.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file4.js
Removing file5.js
Auto-merging file6.json
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in file6.json
Auto-merging file7.jsp
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file7.jsp
Auto-merging file8.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file8.java
Auto-merging file9.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file9.java
Auto-merging file10.java
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in file10.java
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
>> git st
On branch BRANCH-A
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/BRANCH-A'.
You have unmerged paths.
(fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

modified:   .gitignore
modified:   web.xml
deleted:    file5.js
new file:   someFile.js
renamed:    otherFile.css -> anotherFile.css

Unmerged paths:
(use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

both modified:   file8.java
both modified:   file7.jsp
both added:      file6.json
both modified:   file4.js
both modified:   file3.scss
both modified:   file1.css

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   file9.java
modified:   file10.java

>> git st
On branch BRANCH-A
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/BRANCH-A'.
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
(use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

modified:   .gitignore
modified:   web.xml
deleted:    file5.js
new file:   someFile.js
renamed:    otherFile.css -> anotherFile.css

Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   file8.java
modified:   file9.java
modified:   file10.java
modified:   file7.jsp
modified:   file6.json
modified:   file4.js
modified:   file3.scss
modified:   file1.css
```

I know that's a bit verbose, but I want to emphasize that that is literally all I did: merge, check git status, and then check git status again. The second time I checked git status it said all the conflicts were resolved. Alternatively, if I run `git mergetool` immediately after I attempt the merge (and my screen is flooded with CONFLICT messages), I get the message that `No files need merging`.

I have been entirely unsuccessful at finding any record of this happening to anyone else. The only thing I've been able to find is some git config options concerning `trustExitCode`. However, none of those worked either. For the sake of covering all my bases, here is my `~/.gitconfig` file.

```
[color]
    ui = true
[core]
    editor = vim
    excludesfile = /Users/ganders/.gitignore_global
[alias]
    st = status
    co = checkout
    br = branch
    cm = commit
    logtree = log --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%h%Creset%C(auto)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr)%C(blue) [%an]%Creset'
[push]
    default = simple
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
[merge]
    tool = opendiff
[mergetool "opendiff"]
    cmd = /usr/bin/opendiff
    trustExitCode = false
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = 
    trustExitCode = false
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = false
```

I alternate between using git on the command line and SourceTree. My command line version of Git is 2.3.6 installed from Homebrew. I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling git as well as deleting and re-clonining my git repository, all with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> All conflicts fixed but you are still merging. (use "git commit" to
>   conclude merge)

Base on the message. I think you need to add all changes and commit the related files.

Answer (score 0):

I was also troubled by a similar *mergetool/"No files need merging"* situation today, with git on windows.

So, I tried a little hack to find where the **"No files need merging"** message was printed.

It turned out to be **git-mergetool**, a shell-script.

```
if test -z "$files"
then
    echo "No files need merging"
    exit 0
fi
```

the value of **$files** was set some lines before:
(under the if-branch depending the number of parameters, or rerere settings)

```
files=$(git rerere remaining)
files=$(git ls-files -u | sed -e 's/^[^    ]*    //' | sort -u)
files=$(git ls-files -u -- "$@" | cut -f 2 | sort -u)
```

My situation is a little wired -- It seemed that **git ls-files** didn't return synchronously; I had to add some delay after the assignment, then **$files** won't be empty.

No time for me to dig further. Hope such experience would help.